Function that changes object values, type of key and value
I have an async store in Node.js, described by a type:
type IStore = {
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  id: string;
  logins: number;
}

function updateValues(key: keyof IStore, value: unknown) {
  
}

updateValues("name", "1234")

How can i get value to be the right type of submitted key? So if i say updateValues("startDate", new Date()) the value has to be of type Date. Or if it is name, value has to be of type name. Never worked with generics before :-/

Presumably you want it to be generic, like <K extends keyof IAsyncStore>(key: K, value: IAsyncStore[K]), but without a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and test directly, that's just conjecture. Could you [edit] to provide such an example? It would have to either define enough of the class so that stuff like this._instance wasn't an error, or even better, remove the class stuff and just make a standalone function.

Thanks for your answer. The idea with generics looks like the best ive seen. I've copied it to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/clever-stallman-hm9l8r?workspaceId=0d01c121-d607-4571-bf35-95d997e9518d

All code for questions on Stack Overflow should exist on Stack Overflow. See the answers to Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? for the reasoning.

Yes, please [edit] to copy the code you need into the question itself. I would do it for you, but I don't have the rights to that code. Also, a [mre] should be self-contained, so unless it needs express/node/async_hooks to make sense, the code shouldn't probably use that code. Currently this still doesn't have enough debugging details for SO and it might get closed.

I tested the answer of jcalz and used the weekend to read about generics. Great, thanks a lot :)

Does this answer your question? Getting type of a property of a TypeScript class using keyof operator. @jcalz has an answer there which matches

Please don't edit your question to be an answer. I'd recommend leaving it as it is now and accepting the duplicate (and throw an upvote towards the answers that help)
